# Load specific portion of the view on click using ViewComponent

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

In my cshtml file

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.allFontCategory)
    {
        <a asp-controller="Fonts" asp-action="GetFonts" asp-route-id="@item.Item1" class="font-category-name">@item.Item2</a><br />
    }
<div class="col-lg-8" id="font-viewcomponent">
    @* Display fonts*@
</div>
```

In my js file

```
var url = '/Fonts/GetFonts/';
$('.font-category-name').click(function () {
    $('#font-viewcomponent').load(url);
});
```

In my controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.allFontCategory = dataService.getAllFontCategory();
        return View();
    }
public IActionResult GetFonts(int id)
    {
        return ViewComponent("FontAdmin");
    }
```

I am trying to update the content of `#font-viewcomponent` div element when clicking on the anchor tag helper using ASP.NET Core MVC's `ViewComponent`.

When I implement same thing  with partial view in MVC5, it works good. But with ASP.NET Core MVC's `ViewComponent` it would not work and return the `Defalut.cshtml` file as separate view not load as specific portion of the view.

Comment: Is that your whole cshtml? A ViewComponent isn't actually the same as  a partial in MVC5. A ViewComponent has logic and is a self-sustaining piece of code which can be reused. A PartialView is just a template. Also please, for sake of all that's holly, **don't use asp.net-mvc6** tag when you mean "ASP.NET Core MVC". What was called MVC6 during beta and rc1 is now called ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0 and this reflects in the package name. People here spend plenty of time fixing this mistagged questions and you will get less answers as they are less frequently monitored by the community

Comment: Thank you for correction. yes this is my whole cshtml file? I am just making small piece of code to learn view component. I know that view component has logic and code can be reused. If I am calling async method from view like following:

@await Component.InvokeAsync("FontAdmin", 1) then it works fine. but I want to pass id instead of static argument that's why I moved everything to controller and try to load simple view in my Index.cshtml file. And then make it dynamic. But I failed.

Comment: You can prevent the layout from rendering, if you put `@{ Layout = null; }` at the top of your cshtml file, if that's one issue. However, you should note that ViewComponents by default coding conventions expect the cshtml file to be in `Views/<controller_name>/Components/<view_component_name>/<view_name>` or `Views/Shared/Components/<view_component_name>/<view_name>`. it won't find the views if it's not in the Components folder. It's already stated in the documentation here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html

Comment: No that's not the issue. I am following same document to make view component. I normally use second approach to put my view component but I tried also first one, I got same result.

Comment: I guess I pretty much messed up with routing. I removed MVC6 tag helpers, put simple link and also made ajax request on GetFonts then I got the perfect result to load specific portion of the view without refreshing.